# Flutter - how to pass a list of date to selectableDayPredicate in showDatePicker?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the following code to enables some dates (24 June and 25 June in this example) to be able to pick from the DatePicker.

```
   final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
            context: context,
            initialDate: DateTime(2020, 6, 24),
            firstDate: DateTime(2020, 6, 24),
            lastDate: DateTime(2101),
          selectableDayPredicate: (DateTime val) =>
          val == DateTime(2020, 6, 24) || val == DateTime(2020, 6, 25) ? true : false,
        );
```

Note that the `val == DateTime(2020, 6, 24) || val == DateTime(2020, 6, 25)` are hardcoded. I have a list of dates, how to pass it to `selectableDayPredicate`? I have tried the following way as suggested by Anoop, but it is not working.

```
List<DateTime> _dates = List();
_dates.add(DateTime(2020, 6, 24));
_dates.add(DateTime(2020, 6, 25));

 final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: DateTime(2020, 6, 24),
        firstDate: DateTime(2020, 6, 24),
        lastDate: DateTime(2101),
      selectableDayPredicate: (DateTime val) =>
          _dates.contains(_dates),
    );
```

I got the error:

`'selectableDayPredicate == null || selectableDayPredicate(initialDate)': Provided initialDate 2020-06-24 00:00:00.000 must satisfy provided selectableDayPredicate.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can change

```
_dates.contains(_dates)
```

to

```
_dates.contains(val)
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  List<DateTime> _dates = List();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _dates.add(DateTime(2020, 6, 24));
    _dates.add(DateTime(2020, 6, 25));
  }

  void _incrementCounter() async {
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime(2020, 6, 24),
      firstDate: DateTime(2020, 6, 24),
      lastDate: DateTime(2101),
      selectableDayPredicate: (DateTime val) => _dates.contains(val),
    );

    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How would you inverse this code so that the list of dates would NOT be pickable?

Answer (score 1):

If the list is in DateTime format just use List contains method

```
List<DateTime> dates = List(); //list of dates
final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime(2020, 6, 24),
      firstDate: DateTime(2020, 6, 24),
      lastDate: DateTime(2101),
      selectableDayPredicate: (DateTime val) =>
      dates.contains(val), 
 );
```

or list items is in string format convert list into DateTime by DateTime.parse(datestring)

Comment: Help, please check my edited question. It is not working.

Comment: sorry dude i will update the  answer, instead of dates val should be passed on dates.contains(dates)